# Change the color of an element to click

Tags: html, css, svg, path, target

When the picture (or text 'fff') is clicked, i would like the edges of the course on svg (css racing) to become black.

For this, I used the attribute :target but it doesn't works. :(

Could someone help me? Thank you very much.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400);
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
body {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-family: Roboto, Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.map {
  max-width: 1000px !important;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
.map__image path {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  transition: fill 0.3s;
}
#mapApparition:target {
  stroke: blue;
}
.map__image path:hover {
  fill: #a3a3a3;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  transition: fill 0.3s;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #45408A !important;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-box">
      <div class="active-content">
        <div class="home-page content-wrapper">
          <h2>DECOUVEZ NOS ECOLES</h2>
          <p> <a href="#mapApparition"> fff<img src="logo1.png"> </a> 
          </p>
        </div>
        <!-- end of home page -->
      </div>
      <!-- end of active content -->

    </div>
    <!-- end of container -->

    <div class="hidden-content content-wrapper map">
      <div id="map">
        <div id="set-2">
          <div class="map__image hi-icon-wrap hi-icon-effect-2 hi-icon-effect-2a">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 900 600" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
              <a href="" id="mapApparition">
                <path id="1a" d="M409.365,311.989l11.138,4.767l6.815,5.008l8.461,10.026l3.301,3.398l9.171,4.61l6.688,-12.932l13.995,-38.406l-47.324,-17.09l-13.994,-3.649l-14.363,-4.417l-3.499,-2.688l-2.578,-2.881l-4.419,-4.608l-15.836,4.416l-13.181,31.02l6.461,2.074l20.133,11.325l29.031,10.027Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" class="hi-icon" />
              </a>
              <a href="" id="">
                <path id="mapApparition" d="M468.636,288.59l13.542,-35.711l-55.077,-12.9l-44.4,13.035l6.641,7.197l4.166,3.395l11.979,3.394l8.463,2.444l6.641,1.494l48.045,17.652Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
              <clipPath id="_clip1">
                <path id="path60021" d="M468.636,288.59l13.542,-35.711l-55.077,-12.9l-44.4,13.035l6.641,7.197l4.166,3.395l11.979,3.394l8.463,2.444l6.641,1.494l48.045,17.652Z" clip-rule="nonzero" />
              </clipPath>
              <g clip-path="url(#_clip1)">
                <path d="M426.699,257.806l1.414,4.353l4.578,0l-3.704,2.69l1.415,4.354l-3.703,-2.691l-3.703,2.691l1.414,-4.354l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.415,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M442.015,251.679l1.414,4.354l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.415,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.415,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
              </g>
              <a href="">
                <path id="3a" d="M518.114,262.655l12.63,28.651l4.037,41.55l-9.375,-2.851l-12.89,-5.024l-9.115,-5.839l-8.333,-8.69l-9.375,-6.925l-16.145,-5.568l-3.646,-1.222l16.276,-43.994l32.291,8.283l3.645,1.629Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="4a" d="M535.952,351.323l-11.099,30.198l-3.081,7.769l-16.808,-18.413l-2.687,-4.002l-7.188,-4.209l-18.955,-8.746l-8.739,-3.952l-9.812,-5.086l-9.324,-5.104l6.706,-12.896l11.067,-30.416l13.542,5.024l6.38,2.037l4.687,3.802l4.427,3.123l5.599,5.839l2.995,2.987l7.161,4.617l4.427,1.901l7.422,3.123l12.163,3.898l1.378,15.519l-0.261,2.987Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="5a" d="M511.623,423.878l-38.823,18.687l-53.399,-15.363l28.812,-87.308l9.746,4.88l10.42,5.555l5.734,2.626l7.572,3.226l6.266,2.657l6.787,3.473l7.282,4.635l3.189,4.087l8.838,9.986l7.847,8.525l-10.271,34.334Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
                <path d="M444.715,390.077l1.414,4.353l4.578,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.354l-3.703,-2.691l-3.703,2.691l1.414,-4.354l-3.703,-2.69l4.578,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M455.172,393.506l1.415,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M466.144,398.134l1.414,4.353l4.578,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.354l-3.703,-2.691l-3.703,2.691l1.414,-4.354l-3.703,-2.69l4.578,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M460.873,406.105l1.414,4.354l4.578,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.578,0l1.414,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M452.002,403.34l1.414,4.354l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.415,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.415,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M451.465,421.876l1.415,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.691l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.703,-2.691l4.577,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M472.915,425.176l1.414,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.691l1.415,4.353l-3.703,-2.691l-3.703,2.691l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.691l4.577,0l1.415,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M464.194,375.913l1.414,4.354l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.415,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.415,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M453.591,355.955l1.415,4.356l4.581,0l-3.706,2.692l1.416,4.356l-3.706,-2.692l-3.706,2.692l1.416,-4.356l-3.706,-2.692l4.581,0l1.415,-4.356Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="6a" d="M387.063,357.773l20.178,-46.251l13.657,5.202l6.385,5.048l11.49,13.316l9.562,4.369l-28.786,87.703l-33.723,-17.652l-42.121,-22.133l7.096,-6.247l11.133,-6.857l18.033,-14.054l7.096,-2.444Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
                <path d="M415.082,322.281l1.415,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.691l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.704,-2.691l4.578,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a;  stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M428.366,388.17l1.415,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.691l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.703,-2.691l4.577,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a;  stroke:#45408a;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="7a" d="M346.635,287.227l7.381,1.327l6.214,2.275l20.013,11.171l19.071,7.336l7.719,3.256l-19.857,44.903l-7.273,2.785l-17.677,13.826l-11.417,7.105l-6.997,6.145l-8.931,4.609l-7.918,-6.241l-4.695,-4.321l-4.88,1.632l-5.34,2.977l-2.025,0l-12.89,-12.77l-49.932,-43.734l3.003,-5.002l18.761,-24.175l14.414,-7.838l28.272,-5.316l34.984,0.05Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="8a" d="M282.494,292.493l-11.969,-41.575l-11.416,-20.643l12.889,-26.788l106.34,-32.549l0.46,3.552l-1.289,5.569l-1.025,44.35l1.828,5.866l-0.092,2.61l-1.644,1.737l-9.519,23.103l-13.291,31.066l-7.197,-1.509l-34.499,-0.105l-29.576,5.316Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"
                />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="9a" d="M457.977,247.126l-30.889,-7.201l-58.924,17.426l-0.644,-0.48l-0.138,-0.192l9.299,-22.467l1.749,-1.44l0.138,-2.497l-2.072,-5.713l1.013,-44.695l1.381,-5.569l-0.644,-3.264l5.063,-1.68l3.085,-3.745l1.979,0l34.066,13.538l2.348,0l30.014,-9.025l8.24,-0.576l0.184,22.755l-4.235,22.324l-0.875,12.098l-0.138,20.403Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
                <clipPath id="_clip2">
                  <path id="path60161" d="M457.977,247.126l-30.889,-7.201l-58.924,17.426l-0.644,-0.48l-0.138,-0.192l9.299,-22.467l1.749,-1.44l0.138,-2.497l-2.072,-5.713l1.013,-44.695l1.381,-5.569l-0.644,-3.264l5.063,-1.68l3.085,-3.745l1.979,0l34.066,13.538l2.348,0l30.014,-9.025l8.24,-0.576l0.184,22.755l-4.235,22.324l-0.875,12.098l-0.138,20.403l0,0Z"
                  clip-rule="nonzero" />
                </clipPath>
                <g clip-path="url(#_clip2)">
                  <path d="M444.991,223.937l1.414,4.354l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.415,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.415,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a;  stroke:#45408a;" />
                </g>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="10a" d="M462.765,169.498l20.9,-2.689l16.388,-1.44l3.775,-0.768l29.369,0.48l9.023,12.386l1.013,24.292l0.368,2.016l23.11,32.069l-6.353,2.784l-18.138,11.042l-5.708,3.841l-18.506,9.121l-3.867,-1.728l-32.224,-8.161l-23.938,-5.665l0.184,-21.412l0.829,-11.905l4.235,-21.412l-0.46,-22.851Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="11a" d="M566.42,235.77l5.209,7.06l34.895,42.637l8.723,29.058l7.813,3.395l9.505,7.061l15.754,31.095l1.563,12.356l1.172,4.617l-47.525,-8.554l-13.802,-0.815l-19.921,-5.16l-5.99,-1.086l-17.447,-8.691l-10.807,-7.196l-4.688,-50.105l-12.629,-28.787l17.968,-9.233l8.593,-5.567l14.844,-8.962l6.771,-3.123Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="12a" d="M698.918,378.554l-33.281,-3.332l-14.714,-2.037l-47.785,-8.962l-13.932,-0.679l-18.489,-4.752l-6.901,-1.222l-18.098,-9.234l-9.375,-6.246l-0.844,0.043l0.737,6.049l-1.744,5.038l-9.957,28.615l-2.537,7.508l21.266,25.929l17.511,21.097l15.426,21.429l20.9,26.816l10.147,8.715l13.003,-10.905l15.519,-2.936l12.793,-7.55l7.13,0.21l5.034,4.404l8.179,11.744l7.34,5.243l10.486,2.726l16.567,0.21l9.018,5.033l31.038,-1.048l20.972,20.552l-0.629,3.146l1.258,1.678l6.292,-1.049l3.146,2.517l-0.629,4.614l10.066,-0.839l7.76,3.984l28.731,-1.258l11.954,5.453l19.504,-1.468l12.163,-9.857l13.003,-45.719l-2.727,-0.419l-3.774,1.678l0.838,-16.987l3.356,-7.97l6.921,-7.13l5.452,-2.097l2.097,-16.149l-7.13,-13.422l-10.696,-14.051l-7.13,-4.613l-21.601,-5.873l-34.394,-6.726l-2.097,-5.018l-19.023,-0.879l-1.739,8.848l-8.808,-0.629l-1.136,15.924l-17.027,2.639l-17.724,-5.181l-13.412,-0.297l-6.092,-11.816l-2.752,-0.716l-5.611,5.319l-0.63,11.115l4.195,9.438l3.984,20.552l-18.874,10.486l-7.969,2.097l-7.97,-0.21l-3.565,-2.516l5.872,-5.872l8.179,-40.056l2.936,-16.988l0.023,-6.141Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="13a" d="M441.129,545.081l2.301,-7.749l-5.34,-15.651l-1.749,-13.442l2.026,-6.049l-1.842,-28.228l-0.368,-8.738l2.946,-32.453l33.513,9.698l39.007,-18.6l10.375,-34.447l18.575,22.374l12.517,14.872l9.388,12.035l8.539,12l8.161,10.808l18.041,22.71l9.623,8.969l-12.596,6.431l-16.778,9.857l-10.485,8.388l-50.123,24.118l-8.598,3.355l-11.954,-0.209l-13.422,-2.097l-7.55,-11.954l-2.517,0l-7.34,6.291l-9.647,6.292l-9.647,-0.21l0.21,4.614l-1.678,-0.21l-3.588,-2.775Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
              <clipPath id="_clip3">
                <path id="path82051" d="M441.129,545.081l2.301,-7.749l-5.34,-15.651l-1.749,-13.442l2.026,-6.049l-1.842,-28.228l-0.368,-8.738l2.946,-32.453l33.513,9.698l39.007,-18.6l10.375,-34.447l18.575,22.374l12.517,14.872l9.388,12.035l8.539,12l8.161,10.808l18.041,22.71l9.623,8.969l-12.596,6.431l-16.778,9.857l-10.485,8.388l-50.123,24.118l-8.598,3.355l-11.954,-0.209l-13.422,-2.097l-7.55,-11.954l-2.517,0l-7.34,6.291l-9.647,6.292l-9.647,-0.21l0.21,4.614l-1.678,-0.21l-3.588,-2.775l0,0Z"
                clip-rule="nonzero" />
              </clipPath>
              <g clip-path="url(#_clip3)">
                <path d="M547.31,427.015l1.414,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.691l1.415,4.353l-3.703,-2.691l-3.703,2.691l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.691l4.577,0l1.415,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M485.607,470.388l1.415,4.354l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.704,-2.69l4.578,0l1.414,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M516.124,480.732l1.415,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.415,4.353l-3.704,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
              </g>
              <a href="">
                <path id="14a" d="M306.222,499.805l2.604,-10.481l11.693,-16.419l5.984,-7.393l22.833,-33.029l15.652,-19.875l2.025,1.44l7.826,-10.273l44.377,23.331l20.071,5.665l-3.222,32.357l2.21,37.158l-1.934,5.857l1.842,14.018l5.247,15.267l-2.419,7.671l-5.312,-2.486l-32.716,-0.419l-0.629,-9.438l-96.132,-32.951Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
                <path d="M425.931,459.63l1.414,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.415,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.415,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                <path d="M415.72,435.465l1.415,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="15a" d="M158.334,448.578l36.996,-57.465l9.883,-14.518l14.92,-14.163l24.526,-26.401l1.591,-4.93l1.729,-1.352l46.024,40.612l16.112,15.747l1.841,0l5.156,-2.977l5.064,-1.728l5.432,4.801l6.997,5.473l9.207,-4.321l30.751,16.034l-7.826,10.466l-1.749,-1.248l-16.112,20.739l-22.281,32.261l-6.997,8.258l-10.772,15.074l-2.276,11.32l-14.088,-5.043l-29.151,-10.276l-13.212,-6.292l-15.939,-12.793l-21.181,-11.534l-3.146,8.598l-17.826,17.826l-18.036,0.42l-0.21,-22.44l8.809,-6.711l-8.389,-6.711l-15.847,3.274Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
                <path d="M329.27,404.492l1.415,4.354l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.414,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="16a" d="M158.485,448.264l21.897,-33.767l24.982,-38.007l15.444,-14.897l24.002,-25.772l1.591,-5.034l3.721,-6.49l18.977,-23.801l8.441,-5.032l5.034,-3.004l-12.11,-41.482l-11.458,-20.776l-42.982,-19.238l-6.611,1.553l-66.48,-13.422l-11.954,35.233l-31.667,-13.632l-2.727,-0.21l-15.1,24.328l-26.214,11.324l-1.888,-2.936l-14.261,19.714l-7.549,17.616l-9.018,31.248l1.887,10.067l-1.048,12.792l52.01,17.197l9.227,13.212l25.586,10.067l10.695,0.21l0.42,4.823l-5.033,9.647l1.677,4.404l0.21,19.294l10.067,12.164l3.355,9.018l22.859,3.984l4.018,-0.395Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
                <clipPath id="_clip4">
                  <path id="path82131" d="M158.485,448.264l21.897,-33.767l24.982,-38.007l15.444,-14.897l24.002,-25.772l1.591,-5.034l3.721,-6.49l18.977,-23.801l8.441,-5.032l5.034,-3.004l-12.11,-41.482l-11.458,-20.776l-42.982,-19.238l-6.611,1.553l-66.48,-13.422l-11.954,35.233l-31.667,-13.632l-2.727,-0.21l-15.1,24.328l-26.214,11.324l-1.888,-2.936l-14.261,19.714l-7.549,17.616l-9.018,31.248l1.887,10.067l-1.048,12.792l52.01,17.197l9.227,13.212l25.586,10.067l10.695,0.21l0.42,4.823l-5.033,9.647l1.677,4.404l0.21,19.294l10.067,12.164l3.355,9.018l22.859,3.984l4.018,-0.395l0,0Z"
                  clip-rule="nonzero" />
                </clipPath>
                <g clip-path="url(#_clip4)">
                  <path d="M150.585,383.39l1.414,4.354l4.578,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.415,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                  <path d="M215.933,264.947l1.414,4.354l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.415,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.414,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.415,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                  <path d="M255.073,291.155l1.415,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                </g>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="17a" d="M385.136,88.59l-1.734,9.088l-10.036,53.673l4.696,17.666l0,2.017l-31.764,9.697l-17.217,5.281l-33.329,10.178l-23.754,7.393l-12.889,26.692l-41.488,-18.968l3.537,-21.44l2.726,-6.92l9.857,-12.164l26.634,-20.342l10.905,-0.839l44.251,-34.814l40.056,-18.664l10.486,-6.711l19.063,-0.823Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="18a" d="M535.063,83.727l6.618,16.121l-0.13,2.987l-13.671,53.092l-6.38,9.098l-17.708,-0.543l-3.125,0.95l-17.838,1.358l-20.052,2.988l-7.942,0.271l-29.557,9.098l-2.994,0l-33.984,-13.443l-1.823,-0.136l-2.864,3.531l-5.99,2.172l0.521,-1.901l-4.818,-18.195l10.156,-53.907l1.592,-8.331l31.751,-0.992l36.281,-0.63l18.665,-1.677l49.493,-1.468l13.799,-0.443Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
                <clipPath id="_clip5">
                  <path id="path82191" d="M535.063,83.727l6.618,16.121l-0.13,2.987l-13.671,53.092l-6.38,9.098l-17.708,-0.543l-3.125,0.95l-17.838,1.358l-20.052,2.988l-7.942,0.271l-29.557,9.098l-2.994,0l-33.984,-13.443l-1.823,-0.136l-2.864,3.531l-5.99,2.172l0.521,-1.901l-4.818,-18.195l10.156,-53.907l1.592,-8.331l31.751,-0.992l36.281,-0.63l18.665,-1.677l49.493,-1.468l13.799,-0.443l0,0Z"
                  clip-rule="nonzero" />
                </clipPath>
                <g clip-path="url(#_clip5)">
                  <path d="M448.394,126.083l1.415,4.353l4.577,0l-3.703,2.691l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.704,-2.691l4.578,0l1.414,-4.353Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                </g>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="19a" d="M676.704,204.539l-10.547,5.431l-11.067,3.938l-30.208,2.308l-17.056,4.481l-22.526,8.419l-18.619,6.925l-22.786,-31.91l-0.651,-2.987l-0.912,-23.491l-9.114,-12.356l-11.067,-0.272l-0.261,-0.679l5.729,-8.011l14.193,-54.722l-0.261,-1.765l-6.568,-16.133l54.02,-0.594l15.1,5.243l4.613,0.419l5.243,2.307l10.277,10.067l10.485,22.649l1.888,14.051l1.258,13.422l1.049,5.663l0.21,16.567l9.856,15.939l11.535,5.033l13.841,4.824l2.346,5.234Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
                <clipPath id="_clip6">
                  <path id="path82211" d="M676.704,204.539l-10.547,5.431l-11.067,3.938l-30.208,2.308l-17.056,4.481l-22.526,8.419l-18.619,6.925l-22.786,-31.91l-0.651,-2.987l-0.912,-23.491l-9.114,-12.356l-11.067,-0.272l-0.261,-0.679l5.729,-8.011l14.193,-54.722l-0.261,-1.765l-6.568,-16.133l54.02,-0.594l15.1,5.243l4.613,0.419l5.243,2.307l10.277,10.067l10.485,22.649l1.888,14.051l1.258,13.422l1.049,5.663l0.21,16.567l9.856,15.939l11.535,5.033l13.841,4.824l2.346,5.234Z"
                  clip-rule="nonzero" />
                </clipPath>
                <g clip-path="url(#_clip6)">
                  <path d="M619.932,140.718l1.415,4.354l4.577,0l-3.703,2.69l1.414,4.353l-3.703,-2.69l-3.703,2.69l1.415,-4.353l-3.703,-2.69l4.577,0l1.414,-4.354Z" style="fill:#45408a; stroke:#45408a;" />
                </g>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <path id="20a" d="M698.058,378.345l-28.776,-2.716l-18.098,-2.308l-0.912,-3.938l-1.822,-13.171l-16.146,-31.231l-9.114,-6.925l-7.682,-3.531l-8.594,-27.293l-0.521,-1.765l-17.187,-21.318l-18.098,-21.454l-4.427,-6.654l31.249,-11.677l10.677,-3.938l16.406,-4.345l30.207,-2.173l11.328,-4.074l9.975,-5.233l9.579,17.773l3.356,13.212l2.097,68.997l3.356,16.778l0.209,14.051l5.243,29.151l-2.305,13.782Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
                <path id="path8225" d="M698.058,378.345l-28.776,-2.716l-18.098,-2.308l-0.912,-3.938l-1.822,-13.171l-16.146,-31.231l-9.114,-6.925l-7.682,-3.531l-8.594,-27.293l-0.521,-1.765l-17.187,-21.318l-18.098,-21.454l-4.427,-6.654l31.249,-11.677l10.677,-3.938l16.406,-4.345l30.207,-2.173l11.328,-4.074l9.975,-5.233l9.579,17.773l3.356,13.212l2.097,68.997l3.356,16.778l0.209,14.051l5.243,29.151l-2.305,13.782Z"
                style="fill-rule:nonzero;" />
              </a>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i guess that you could find what you want to achieve just by googling around the web

Comment: I would love to but I do not find this.